# Remove space of a string in template file

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, jinja2

I'm new to python and django. I'm playing with a travel site with a different destination. I want to create a link for the destination from the name of it, some make it lower and delete the whitespace.
The .lower work but .replace(" ", "") give me an error

> Could not parse the remainder: '(" ", "")' from
>   'dest.name.lower.replace(" ", "")'

```
{% for dest in dests %}

<div class="destination_title"><a href="{{ dest.name.lower.replace(" ","")}}.html">{{ dest.name }}</a></div>

{% endfor %}
```

If the city is San Francisco, the result should be sanfrancisco

Thanks in advice and sorry for my English

Comment: Apart from the syntax issue, you shouldn't be doing this in the template anyway. You need to store the slug on the destination model; otherwise, how will the destination page itself find the relevant item? And there's no need to add ".html" to the URL.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank for your reply, I will add a new field to the user model. Thanks!

Comment: Could the error be due to you using double quotes inside of double quotes, maybe try `dest.name.lower.replace(‘ ‘, ‘’)`

Comment: Thanks but I have the same error with single quotes

Answer (score 1):

Use **cut**

Removes all values of arg from the given string.

```
{{ dest.name.lower|cut:' '}
```